# Chromium File Chooser out of display

Tags: angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, filechooser

I'm currently working on an Angular Application which will run on a Raspberry Pi.
The Raspberry Pi has a small touchscreen display (comparable to a smartphone) connected where the user can view and interact with the application.
Right now I'm using the chromium browser in kiosk mode and it works nearly perfect.

Since the application has the option to load and display files from local storage I added a possibility to choose files. This is the point where I struggle to find a nice a solution because the file chooser of the browser is to big for the small screen and the user is only able to see half of the file chooser.

What I've tried already:

1. Tried to use a mobile file chooser in desktop mode
2. Searched for alternative file-chooser extensions
3. Searched for possibilities to somehow style the file-chooser itself

Right now I'm running out of ideas and I was wondering if anybody has ideas for me what I could try next?
Suggestions for other browsers etc. are also very welcome. Anything that would make the user experience better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a small python application using flask to write my own file-chooser.
The application has two endpoints:

1. `getAllFilesInDir()` which will return a list of all file names available in a specific folder
2. `getFileContent(filename)` which will return the content of the chosen file

This solution allows me to display the "file-chooser" with a styling that works for my use-case.

Didn't think about this in first place but it works out really nice and is very easy to implement.
Just posting this in case someone is facing a similar problem and does not come up with a solution immediately (like me).